# What to set $u$ as in integration by substitution

Tags: integration

> $$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}\
>  \mathrm{d}x$$

The question asks me to use a trigonometric substitution so I tried $u=\sin x$ but that doesn't give me nice $x$ limit values so I'm not sure. I saw a guy using $u=\sec x$ but I don't understand how or why he knew to use that

Comment: Differentiate $sin^3 (x)$ and you want $x = sin(u)$ not $u = sin(x)$

Comment: why would I want to differentiate $sin^3x$?

Comment: You can let $x=\sin y.$ Or if you want an algebraic substitution let $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}.$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in a rush. Thought integrand was $sin^2 (x)cos(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $x=\sin(u)$. First of all the boundaries become
$$\arcsin \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} = \frac{\pi}{3}, \quad \arcsin \frac{1}{2} = \frac{\pi}{6}.$$
Calculating the differential: $\mathrm{d}x = \cos u\,\mathrm{d}u$:
$$\int\limits_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}\sin^2 u\cos^2 u\,\mathrm{d}{u}.$$